# Select microphone source from headset instead of handy mic

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, microphone, headset

is it possible to record audio from my Bluetooth headset instead of using the integrated android smartphone microphone?
When i am connecting my headset to my phone I can use the mic while I am phoning but in any other case it does not record anything, for example when I am trying to record audio with a recording app it uses the mic from the phone. SO is there any solution for selecting the headset mic instead or can  I write an application for it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the following intent.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_VOICE_SEARCH_HANDS_FREE

You can use the following code to use bluetooth headset mic.

```
AudioManager audiomanager= (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context
            .AUDIO_SERVICE);
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED);
    mContext.registerReceiver(mBluetoothScoReceiver, intentFilter);
audiomanager.startBluetoothSco();
```

and listen for the broadcast receiver.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBluetoothScoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1);

        if (state == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED) {
            // Start recording audio
            log("audio connected");
            startRecording();
        } else if(state == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED){
            log("audio disconnected");
        }
    }
};
```

and for switching(to disconnect bluetooth headset mic) you can use this code.

```
mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
```

Comment: In my case i always goes to the disconnected block , any reason why ? i have the same exact code